# IOS 8, Objective C and Xcode 6: creating a dynamic grid with cells containing different UICollectionViews

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6, uicollectionview

I'm trying to build an application without storyboard. Thus I want to set up a grid which enables the user to have a kind of dynamic layout in function of interface orientation and screen size as well.

Below please find two images which show the grid in two different interface orientations - portrait and landscape. There should be always a fixed top, left and right border - undependently of the screen size and interface orientation.

The yellow grid represents a headline only - thus nothing special - with the only exception that in portrait mode it should be placed at the leftmost position.

The two other grids (cells) should contain two different UICollectionViews.

[SORRY: I just figured out that I can't load up any images as I'm still a newbie here! ]

The main issue is the following: 
How would you build the main grid (with the three mentioned cells)?

The first idea which comes into my mind is to create an UICollectionView with three cells.
But in such case, we would have nested UICollectionViews, thus CollectionView1 and CollectionView2 embedded in MainCollectionView. The main problem would consist in three different delegates in the main view controller (representing the main view with the grid) - consequently the code would be likely to be blown up and unreadable - imagine only the method (among others)

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { ... }

which would contain three different distinctions of collectionViews to handle.

Have you got another idea to realize such project without bulking up the code too much?
Any idea is highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

```html
<h2>Portrait</h2>
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=1>
  <tr>
    <td width=300 height=50 colspan=2 bgcolor="yellow" align="center">Headline</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width=100 height=100 bgcolor="blue" align="center">CollectionView 1</td>
    <td width=200 bgcolor="red" align=center>CollectionView 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<h2>Landscape</h2>
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=1>
  <tr>
    <td width=50 height=80 bgcolor="yellow" align="center">Headline</td>
    <td width=120 height=100 bgcolor="blue" align="center">CollectionView 1</td>
    <td width=300 bgcolor="red" align="center">CollectionView 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: "Below please find two images ..." ?

Comment: Sorry - I can't upload any images! I've just created my account ..

Comment: You certainly don't need a collection view for your 3 grids; just use auto layout to position them. It's hard to advise you further without seeing your images. There are lots of places you can upload images to - you should do that so we can see what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot, rdelmar!
Thus I would build an UIView with auto layout, containing a label and two different CollectionViews? Sounds much easier than to embed all in a super CollectionView ...

Answer (score 0):

Now I've resolved my problem in an easy way:

1. Main ViewController has two different Views -> auto layout
2. Each View from 1) has a CollectionView -> borders to embedding
   view = 0
3. Each CollectionView points its delegate and dataSource to the embedding
   view, rather than to the main ViewController -> loose coupling, each
   CollectionView can be handled separately, without the obligation to make case
   distinctions (as for example in cellForItemAtIndexPath)

My solution works perfectly - in addition, code is now more maintainable than before.